# save unicode character in db2 iSeries with .net dataset

Tags: .net, unicode, ado.net, db2, dataset

I try to save the trademark symbol (™) in a DB2 iSeries database. The column encoding uses CCSID 1200 and inserting / selecting using native sql works fine. When I'm trying to save it using a .net dataset in C#, I get a conversion error. As far, as I understood, the DB2 data provider sends in binary format as default, so this should work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Define explicitly, with message identifier and text, what is the "*conversion error*"; might best also share a code snippet of what is done to *save it using a .net dataset in C#*. Sending *binary* text to UTF tagged columns is quite nearly unsupported; much like casting between BINARY and character types is nigh impossible. Note: The `DB2` tag is generic whereas a `DB2i` tag identifies the DB2 for IBM i [or for the older DB2 for IBM i5/OS as the previously-known-as DB2/400, the `DB2400` tag does similarly], as differentiated from the other DB2 variants.

Comment: The only information I get is "A conversion error occurred", nothing more. The code is standard ADO.NET dataset, nothing special. I meant that the SQL is sent as SQL_BINARY, not the column itself (at least this is what the documentation of the provider says).

Answer (score 0):

try to insert into varchar column like this

```
insert into jgrun.tmp2    
values x'39'
```

Comment: Intending to accomplish what? As 7-bit ASCII that would be the digit `'9'`, and as EBCDIC that would be a control character. Certainly that could not be a sneaky way of getting the ™ Trade Mark Sign (U+2122) or UTF8 0xE2 0x84 0xA2 inserted into the table via C#?